# This app will be impacted by a change in the Google Play policy governing the use of SMS and CALL_LOG permissions

Tags: android

I receive the following above warning (in subject) from Google Developer Console:

My Mainfest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

Gradle:

```
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 28

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
implementation 'com.anjlab.android.iab.v3:library:1.0.44'                           //in-app billing
implementation "com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2"                                 //picasso
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.9.1'                  //ExoPlayer
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.9.1'                  //ExoPlayer
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.9.1'                    //ExoPlayer
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.9.1'       //ExoPlayer
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls'                         //ExoPlayer
implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0'                             //Video Streamer (uses ExoPlayer)
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'                                  //NavDrawer
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'                    //AdMob
}
```

I am not requesting any permissions for `SMS and CALL_LOG` so not sure what to do, the Mainfest should be the one and only file to request these permissions (which it is not doing), please help?

Comment: I once have an app which contains the word 'Message' in the title even though it doesn't really require SMS and CALL_LOG permissions. I unpublished it and gave it a new name.

Comment: Hi,
I got the same warning and just like you do not use any call/sms related permission. I asked google support but no response yet. DId you get any update from Google? Thanks

Comment: Did your app get approved? If yes then how you fix this issue. I'm facing the same issue with my application and i have also only listed READ_PHONE_STATE permission

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this and it was very frustrating, but I finally figured out what was happening.

The permissions for older versions of Android were different, and if you have a certain permission and you target an old android version, then the system interprets your permission to include other permissions.

I ran `aapt dump badging myapp.apk`

and I found this:

> uses-implied-permission: name='android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG'
>   reason='targetSdkVersion < 16 and requested READ_CONTACTS'

So, I didn't ACTUALLY have that permission listed, but it was assuming it because I had a low target api number.

Raise your `targetSdkVersion` and it should be fixed.

Comment: Did the warning show the whole time or only once after a while within the Play console?

Comment: @Panther I believe it only started showing when Google instituted a new policy. We fixed it in the way described above, but then Google still removed our app after the deadline and we're still trying to figure out why.